# how to correctly format date that returns from webservice c#

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, date-formatting

in my .js file, i call a c# webservice.

```
function getDetailsFromDb(id_mac, id_instance) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "webMethods/GetData.asmx/getServicesById",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        idMacchina: id_mac,
        idIstanza: id_instance
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        var itemsLoaded = msg.d;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

This function returns a set of objects, that i got from my database.
one of theese fields, returns a date, in the followning format:

```
/Date(1467878700750)/
```

Now, i need to get from that string, day, month, year, hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds. 
how can i get theese informations?

thanks in advance

Comment: Useful if instead you want to parse that value in JS: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT). In JavaScript, you can create a `Date` instance for it by:

1. Isolating the number from the string
2. Converting it to a number
3. Then using `new Date`, which accepts milliseconds-since-the-Epoch:

E.g.,

```js
var theString = "/Date(1467878700750)/";
var theNumber = +theString.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//)[1];
console.log(theNumber);
var dt = new Date(theNumber);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

You can convert *all* of them in the JSON when converting the JSON if you like, by using a *reviver* function:

```js
var rexDateString = /^\/Date\((\d+)\)\/$/;
function dateHandlingReviver(k, v) {
  var match;
  if (typeof v === "string") {
    match = v.match(rexDateString);
    if (match) {
      return new Date(+match[1]);
    }
  }
  return v;
}

var json = '{"date1":"/Date(1467878700750)/","obj":{"date2":"/Date(1467871700750)/"}}';

var result = JSON.parse(json, dateHandlingReviver);
console.log(result);
```

(Note that the `"2016-07-07T08:05:00.750Z"` shown in the console above for those dates is just how the Stack Snippets console shows `Date` objects.)

You'd change your query to tell jQuery *not* to parse it for you by setting `dataType: "text"` instead of `dataType: "json"`, and then parse it yourself using `JSON.parse` with that reviver.

Comment: hi, how can i get seconds and milliseconds too?

Comment: @pasluc74669: Using the various methods on `Date`, like `getSeconds` and `getMilliseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rhcwxLav/

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1467878700750);
document.write(d);
}
```